# Undefined references to functions found within SDL2/SDL2_framerate.h

Tags: linux, sdl-2

I'm having an issue compiling my code which is using the  library.

First of all, I have ran a `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-*` and installed everything they could give me.

Next up, I manually built the darned thing.  I found the source online at [this url](https://git.directory/manaplus/manaplus/blob/08bd81e4db25d054c49fdea16062f23b0eb69fc6/src/sdl2gfx/SDL2_framerate.c).  I'm not exactly sure where to put the compile `.so object` I generated with:

```
gcc -c -fpic -lSDL2 SDL2_framerate.c -o SDL2_framerate.so
```

So I tried to manually compile with the shared object I generated.  No luck, the thing *does* compile, however it segmentation faults on me immediately.  I tried compiling without `-fpic` and still no luck.

The segmentation fault is being caused by `SDL_initFramerate` according to `GDB`.  I'm assuming this is because it's looking for the function in the wrong place, once again, I'm totally uncertain where *exactly* this is supposed to go as I haven't been able to locate where on my system `libsdl2.so` is (or some version of `libsdl2`).

I'm at a loss, I'd like to use what this library has to offer, but it seems like either there is a bug in the library (or more likely a user error), or it's not fully implemented yet.

I'm hoping someone has seen a similar issue to this, or has a better understanding of what's going on and how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Why are you assuming it looks for functions in the wrong place ? At any rate, you need to provide much more information. How do you compile and link your program ? Show the exact commands. Just as important: show your source code that crashes . You're also stating things about undefined reference, which means you didn't produce an executable, yet you also say you're running your program - so it's hard for people to follow along with what you're doing.

Comment: Provided `SDL_initFramerate` code can only fail if `SDL_GetTicks` does, or (far more likely) its argument is a NULL. If your program is linked and runs (i.e. at least reaches `main`) - then there is no visible reason to suspect linking problems. Aside from that, it seems illogical to use dynamic library for so small code instead of just adding it into your program. Also, `.so` creation line looks wrong (`-c` is strange here, it should be just `.o`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong eventually.  First of all, I wasn't passing the FPSmanager object to the correct functions, which means I wasn't using the functions correctly.

Secondly, I figured out that you have to compile it with the -SDL2_gfx linking flag.  Not exactly sure where or how to figure out what compiler flags you need without trial and error (I'm sure there's a nicer way to do it, I just haven't found it).